# One column minus one column

Tags: mysql

I have a looping selecting from each table:

**Orders_keep_table**

```
---------------------------------------
  unique_random    quantity    remain      
---------------------------------------
  12C3EDsE34e        5           5
  sad234sadsa        7           7
```

**Claim_table**

```
-----------------------------
  unique_random    quantity      
-----------------------------
  sad234sadsa        1
```

What I will do here is first check if the column of `unique_random` in two table is filled and match.

If it is matched, then  count the total amount of quantity from the two tables:

From the two table, the `unique_random` which is mathec is the row bumber 2 for `sad234sadsa`.
So, the substract would be: `7-1 = 6`

Please have a look in table `Orders_keep_table` in the column `remain`, there I want to update the count result from `7` to `6`

**HOW??**

Actually I don't want to update it. What I want is like this:

```
        `select * from Orders_keep_table o LEFT JOIN Claim_table c on o.unique_random = c.unique_random WHERE remain = o.quantity - c.quantity;`
```

Comment: WHat did you try so far?

Comment: Not at all because I have no clue so far.

Comment: What do you mean by : *What I will do here is first check if the column of unique_random and Claim_table is filled and match.* ?

Comment: Upss I am sory, i mean `in two table`. Edited

Comment: please have a look at my update question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `UPDATE` statement with `JOIN`. joining both table will find the matched rows based on `unique_random` column then you can perform the UPDATE on `remain` column by subtracting `Quantity` columns value from both table.

```
UPDATE Orders_keep_table o 
    JOIN Claim_table c ON o.unique_random = c.unique_random
SET o.remain = o.quantity - c.quantity;
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to update it. What I want is like this: `select * from Orders_keep_table o LEFT JOIN Claim_table c ON o.unique_random = c.unique_random WHERE remain = o.quantity - c.quantity;` Is it correct to do this?

Comment: @klaudia, Yes. Go ahead and give a try.